# Typescript - Exclude enum values with function

Tags: javascript, typescript, enums

I'm trying to filter out enum values and I have some issues with typings/filtering these entries. I cannot type my filter function correctly. I spent some hours and I have no idea how to do it.

What I want to achieve:

I have enum like:

```js
enum AllEntries {
    A = 'a',
    B = 'b',
    C = 'c',
    D = 'd'
}
```

And I want to have this enum to have some entries filtered out for some keys in array:

```js
const testObject = {
    // this one should have possibility to access all enum keys except A
    withoutA: filterEnum(AllEntries, [AllEntries.A]),

    // this one should have possibility to access all enum keys except A
    all: AllEntries,

    // this one should have possibility to access only D entry
    onlyD: filterEnum(AllEntries, [AllEntries.A, AllEntries.B, AllEntries.D])
}
```

I want function filterEnum to return "clone" of AllEntries without values given in second parameter, also it shouldn't allow me to access eg. A key in testObject.withoutA

I'm trying to use Exclude utility type etc, but with no results. Do you have any ideas?

Example code that shows what I want to achieve (with nasty `any`):

[here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYOwrgtgBAggNnKBvAUFWUC8UDkBDHAGjSgCEtcAjIkgYQpwGMcUBfFFRgexAGcAXKADMAlnH7AATgHkwg7AB4AKlGAAPCSAAmvWAgDaAXQB8ACnWM4YLcABcUJQEosx5CW59Bo8VOBaKptKUAFbAjPwAdADWwACevKbwcM54unggsY4R3hKSpqZR9kmO9lFQIrpJLlAAhBZWNhEiIJbWwAmJCFCp3RmO%20lGGjo7uPLxccMARcFwA5uZqrTaEwmK5fiPoHgJQku1g4vbpsRRI7OhCXJJQptuCeFBcQqs%20e1rOqOjoe7wH-PoPHrHQwBKpAvoAwwkc67YD8MCSECw37iNgcO5QSixADScVOJAA7iJ%20AALLhyGD2HJSWT8Uz6JIRGBDYgkPAIIoIVnoHhwWK0KlrGlyemMmArRmkIZozhjCZTGbzFBY3GxCJE0nk-gwJkrAD0eqkkiuypxcXVxLJFIipH1et4Vrg-gJVyiptVEXZcF1UANDvJTqgLskbpV5t5-JtdqNJrDaojtAitDt-oOztdKEcQA)

Answer (score 1):

First of all, there is no dynamic `Enums`.

It is better to use immutable objects instead of enums, because have issues with number values.

```js
const All = {
  A: 'a',
  B: 'b',
  C: 'c'
} as const;

type All = typeof All;

const remove = <T, P extends keyof T>(obj: T, prop: P) => {
  const { [prop]: _, ...rest } = obj;
  return rest
}

const filterOut = <T extends keyof All>(obj: All, exclude: T[]): Omit<All, T> =>
  exclude.reduce(remove, obj as any)


const withoutA = filterOut(All, ['A']); // ok
const onlyC = filterOut(All, ['A', 'B']) // ok
```

It is hard to make `reduce` in TS without type casting (`as` operator)

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?target=99#code/MYewdgzgLgBAggGwTAvDA3gKBvAXDAcgEMCAabGAIXwICMyKBhG4AzAXxiIhlEigDcmTFACeABwCm8JKhhipIAGYyEQzH2gwATpIC2IAG7S0AHgAqpGAAUYkgB5RJYACY8A1pNHKY5gHwAFCC0AFb4ljDi2iDi%20NYAlKh%20GBSasOgwANpRMQC6%20AD6VgB0pbpanGjBIUI4ulAArtpgOpLQHMJpMEoAlghO2gDyDbBm5naOzm4wnt4qiAiB1fgLVg7ACA0ukuGZufH4g3o9UKarvskofhTrm9vFui4NwJIBugbGVtVcPERgovFhBpwFoAO4nAAWIBGcDkvX6kiGIwC50yBDgBH2AhgAHocTAQO5gfwCWAEKJGHC%20gNhlAUUgrGiMVYCJRMYk8QSiUA)